# Notepad++ regex to find single character bounded by |

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm having trouble coming up with the regex I need to do this find/replace in Notepad++. I'm fine with needing a couple of separate searches to complete the process.

Basically I need to add a `|` at the beginning and end of every line from a CSV, plus replace all the `,` with `|`. Then, on any value with only 1 character, I need to put two spaces around the character on each side ("A" becomes "  A  ")

Source:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6
name,desc,something,else,here,too
another,,three,,,
single,characters,here,a,b,c
last,line,here,,almost,
```

Results:

```
|col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6|
|name|desc|something|else|here|too|
|another||three||||
|single|characters|here|  a  |  b  |  c  |
|last|line|here||almost||
```

Adding the `|` to the beginning and the end of the line is simple enough, and replacing `,` with `|` is obviously straightforward. But I can't come up with the regex to find `|x|` where `x` is limited to a single character. I'm sure it is simple, but I'm new to regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regex:

```
(?:(^)|(?!^)\G)(?:([^\r\n,]{2,})|([^\r\n,]))?(?:(,$)|(,)|($))
```

Replacement string:

```
(?{1}|)(?{2}\2)(?{3}  \3  )(?{4}||)(?{5}|)(?{6}|)
```

Ugly, dirty and long but works.

**Regex Explanation**:

```
(?:                 # Start of non-capturing group (a)
    (^)                 # Assert beginning of line (CP #1)
    |                   # Or
    (?!^)               # //
    \G                  # Match at previous matched position
)                   # End of non-capturing group (a)

(?:                 # Start of non-capturing group (b)
    ([^\r\n,]{2,})      # Match characters with more than 2-char length (any except \r, \n or `,`) (CP #2)
    |                   # Or
    ([^\r\n,])          # Match one-char string (CP #3)
)?                  # Optional - End of non-capturing group (b)

(?:                 # Start of non-capturing group (c) 
    (,$)                # Match `,$` (CP #4)
    |                   # Or
    (,)                 # Match single comma (CP #5)
    |                   # Or
    ($)                 # Assert end of line (CP #6)
)                   # End of non-capturing group (c)
```

Comment: 2:30AM here I'm not fresh to add explanation. But I'll do asap.

Comment: +1 for being a one-step-solution, though I think a multi-step-solution is much more readable (and could be used as a macro)

Comment: For the most part that works. And being one step, while confusing, is efficient. But it seems to fail if there is non-alphanumeric characters in the text. For instance, if `some-value` is in there, it stops at the `-` and moves on to the next line. Tried to work out how to modify it, but I'm not knowledgeable enough in regex to figure out how to do it.

Comment: @MSCF It's a matter of changing `\w` to `[^\r\n,]`. Please check update.

Comment: Works like a champ. And thank you for the explanation. I can see how it works now. I need to study up on regex.

Answer (score 1):

The first replace adds | at the beginning and at the end, and replaces commas:

```
Search: ^|$|,
Replace: |
```

The second replace adds space around single character matches:

```
Search: (?<=[|])([^|])(?=[|])
Replace:   $1
```

Add spaces to the left and to the right of $1.

Comment: Have you tested? The second one doesn't work, even if you escape the pipes.

Comment: @SebastianProske I'm on my iPhone, so I can't test it at the moment. What's wrong with the expression?

Comment: `[|](.)[|]` will match on triple `|` and wont work on sequences of multiple single characters (as `|a|b|c|`)

Comment: @SebastianProske Ah, you are right! Bars will consume the input, so I need to make them into look-arounds.

Comment: Guess you mixed up lookahead and lookbehind. Still problematic on `|||`

Comment: Also your first regex doesn't meet the requirements fully, when there is a comma at the end of line.

Answer (score 1):

Three Step Solution:

- Pattern: `^.+$` Replacement: `|$0|`
- Pattern: `,` Replacement: `|`
- Pattern: `(?<=\|)([^|\r\n])(?=\|)` Replacement:   `$0`